# Store multiple values for multiple times in one column?

Tags: mysql, sql, database, relational-database

With MySQL is there a way to store an array of key/values for a single column? For example, I'm wanting to store a few (3 - 6) different values for times of the day such as this:

```
12AM: 1.2
1AM: 3.0
6AM: 4.0
```

I've seen that doing a relational table might be the right way to do this but I would have no control over the column timeframes or values, they would be user input data. The data here would also link to a single user.

I could have a separate table linked by UID that would have multiple rows with the key/value but wouldn't that be slow in the long run with say 10 million plus rows of data?

Comment: "but wouldn't that be slow in the long run with say 10 million plus rows of data?" No. 10 million rows with a decent index is chump change for a halfways decent database. You can find any value in a table of 10,000,000 with only 25 comparisons (log2 of 10mil is 23.25)

Comment: It will be a lot faster to search 10 million rows of single pieces of data than 2 million rows of (for example) comma separated data, where you won't easily be able to use an index.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

MySQL does not support an array data type, though it supports a [JSON data type](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.7/en/json.html) in MySQL 5.7 and later.

Strictly speaking, you *can* store any kind of semi-structured data you want in a `TEXT` column. But then you will find it's not easy or efficient to search it.

You might find yourself wishing to search your "array" for a specific value. In such a case, you'll be tempted to use `LIKE '%pattern%'` or [regular expression matching](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.7/en/regexp.html) or something like that to find a particular time of day. These expressions are hard to impossible to optimize with indexes, so searches generally become table-scans.

The alternative is to use a child table, with one datetime per row referencing your UID. Yes, this can grow to be a long table with millions of rows, but it is much easier to optimize the search with indexes. An indexes search on a table with millions of rows will beat a non-indexes table-scan search on a much smaller table.

You'll experience less gray hair and have a much happier experience with SQL if you live by the rule that **every column should be one scalar value** — not an "array," or a [comma-separated list](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3653462/is-storing-a-delimited-list-in-a-database-column-really-that-bad/3653574#3653574), or a "document" of JSON or XML, or any other sort of semi-structured data like that.

Comment: Yup, reading into it some more online this seems like the proper solution. Thank you for the detailed explanation.